# Create new column using split() function in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

> I've got a column of a data frame COL-A:

```
COL-A
DE 25
DE 240
BA 14
XI 4R 123
DE 5G 4
XI 2445
```

> I want to create the column COL-B by selecting the last value split by space.
>
> Expected output:

```
COL-A     COL-B
DE 25        25
DE 240      240
BA 14        14
XI 4R 123   123
DE 5G 4       4
XI 2445    2445
```

> Should I use apply function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rsplit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html)+[`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor+[`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method:

```
df['COL-B']=df['COL-A'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[1].astype(int)
#OR
#df['COL-B']=df['COL-A'].str.split().str[-1].astype(int)
```

output of `df`:

```
    COL-A       COL-B
0   DE 25       25
1   DE 240      240
2   BA 14       14
3   XI 4R 123   123
4   DE 5G 4     4
5   XI 2445     2445
```